# Why doesn't my A/C get power when using the alternate C-wire thermostat hook-up method?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, thermostat

I changed my old Honeywell thermostat for a new Honeywell WiFi thermostat. I installed it just as the directions stated.  I used the alternate C-wire method as the old unit did not have one. Everything worked except for getting power to the air conditioner unit outside. I installed the old one back and it works just fine.

Any ideas as to why it doesn't get power with the new thermostat?

Comment: Did you run through the configuration of the thermostat? I know the new one I installed requires you to specify whether it is  a heat only or heat/ac system, as well as gas/electric, High perf or not.

Comment: Could you post a link to the installation instructions you followed, and/or summarize the "alternate C-wire method"?  This will help folks understand exactly what you did.

Comment: Yes I did. I have a gas furnace with central air. I even went through all the settings to make sure I didn't have it wrong. The alternate c-wire method can be found at http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=jniws7wqeY4&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Djniws7wqeY4